# UIButton over UIImageView (over UIScrollView)

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uibutton

I want to show an image (larger then the screen of the iphone), that the user can scroll.
Isn't difficoult, i've done with this code:
in my .h file

```
@interface mappa1 : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
IBOutlet UIImageView *img;
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller;
 }
```

in my .m file

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"prova.jpg"];
img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
scroller.delegate = self;
scroller.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
scroller.contentSize = img.frame.size;
scroller.scrollEnabled = YES;
scroller.directionalLockEnabled = NO;
scroller.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
CGSize ivsize = img.frame.size;
CGSize ssize = scroller.frame.size;

float scalex = ssize.width / ivsize.width;
float scaley = ssize.height / ivsize.height;
scroller.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
scroller.minimumZoomScale = fmin(1.0, fmax(scalex, scaley));
scroller.zoomScale = fmin(1.0, fmax(scalex, scaley));
[scroller addSubview:img];
```

and

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

return img;
```

}

and all works fine!

Now i want to add an UIButton on the UIImage, not on the UIView, because i want that if the user zooms or moves the image, the uibutton follow the movement/zoom of the uiimage.

So i add this code:

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 25);
[btn setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClick)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[img addSubview:btn];
```

but the UIButton is "not-clickable"! 
Of course, the UIView and the UIImageView has UserInteractionEnabled set to YES!

Thanks!

EDIT: if i write

```
[scroller addSubView:btn];
```

it works but, of course, if the user zoom in/out, the UIButton is always big 100x25.

Comment: There's a property of scrollViews "Cancellable Content Touches". You can find it in the attributes inspector in IB. Uncheck that option and then try.

Comment: thank you but no, it doesn't works! Also, if i uncheck "cancellabla content touches", zoom doesn't works!

Comment: You might need to implement resizing manually for the button according to zoom level on the UIImage. So whenever someone zooms on the image you adjust button size.

Comment: yes, with the uibutton over the uiscrollview. the problem is: how can i know how much zoom is the image? But there is no way to add the uibutton on the uiimageview (as in my code) and make the uibutton works?

Comment: For that u have to inherit  the scroll view to detect the subview  and based on that u can give the action event to the same  i Give  U the link that is similar to that but u have to settle every thing as per your requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED! 
I don't know why, but if i checked `UserInteractionEnabled` (on the UIImageView) in Interface Builder, it doesn't works.
If i write

```
img.UserInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

it works!

Answer (score 0):

i tried this and it works for me.......

```
UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpeg"]];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,300,300)];
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];

UIButton * ButtonOnImageView = [[UIButton alloc]init];
[ButtonOnImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(135,120,60,30)];
 [ButtonOnImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpeg"]  forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
 [ButtonOnImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.jpeg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [    ButtonOnImageView addTarget:self action:@selector(OnClickOfTheButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 [imageView addSubview:ButtonOnImageView];
 [self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Answer (score -1):

This Code May be usefull to You

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Listings/MyViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008023-MyViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6